# IPython: save inline graphics to a file?

Tags: matplotlib, save, ipython, inline

Now this question has been asked and answered numerous times before, but I've tried all the answers (except, it would seem, for the correct one), with no success.  I'm running iPython with inline graphics, having used the command

```
ipython qtconsole --matplotlib inline&
```

within linux (Ubuntu 14.04) to start it.  And I want to save graphics to a file.  For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.arange(0,2*np.pi,0.1)
plt.plot(x,np.sin(x))
plt.savefig('myplot.png')
```

However, the file thus generated is empty.  I've tried entering

```
plt.ioff()
```

but this has no effect: the plot is displayed inline anyway.  I'm not quite sure whether my issue is python, ipython, matplotlib, qt, or something else...

I can do this with non-inline graphics; if I start with

```
ipython qtconsole --matplotlib qt&
```

but I like inline graphics.  Is it possible to save inline graphics in ipython?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue on OSX. `myplot.png` contains the plot as expected here.

Comment: Try savefig() from the fig instance instead of plt

Comment: @Alasdair did you try savefig('test.png', bbox_inches='tight')

Answer (score -1):

You can save ipython notebook as html from the menu, which saves all the pictures separately for you:

File -> Download As -> HTML

Comment: Thank you very much - this looks like a possible solution, if a little cumbersome.